# Area using double integrals

Tags: integration, surfaces

My question considers double integrals, and calculating the area of cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$ cut out by $(x^2+y^2)^2=2xy$($z\ge 0$). So the second curve is like infinity symbol in first and third quadrant. After using polar coordinates $x=r\cos\phi$, $y=r\sin\phi$ i get $0\le r\le \sqrt{\sin2\phi}$ and $0\le \phi \le \frac{\pi}{4}$. And after i plug that in formula($\iint \sqrt{1+p^2+q^2}$)i get $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$. But correct answer is apparantley 8 times bigger, which doesn't really make sense to me,because we have restriction $z\ge 0$ so that means whe are watching only cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ right?

Comment: But if $z \geq 0$ then you are off by $4$ times not $8$ times. It should be $\sqrt 2$ and not $2 \sqrt 2$.

Comment: First of all, you have two loops as you mentioned (so you need to multiply the surface area by $2$) - one between $0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and another between  $\pi \leq \phi \leq \frac{3\pi}{2}$. Second, why are you considering $\phi$ only between $0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$? In fact $r$ increases between $0$ and $\pi/4$ and is max at $\pi/4$, and then starts reducing and gets to zero at $\phi = \pi/2$ completing one loop in the first quadrant.

Comment: Okey for the two loops is clear i wanted to do that. But for the ange $\phi$ I am not sure I understood. So after $\frac{\pi}{4}$ we have $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and for both $\sin2\phi$ is positive. So i need to change bounds to $0\le \phi \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ and to multiply the surface with 2(because of two petals) right? Thanks for great answer.

Comment: Yes that is correct. If you draw the first loop, you can see that the loop completes only at $\pi/2$. Starts at radius $0$ at $\phi = 0$ and circles back to radius $0$ at $\phi = \pi /2$.

Comment: Everything clear, thanks a lot. For some reason I am always mistaking when it comes to multiplying area, always missing something.

Comment: You are welcome. I am sure it will get better as you practice more.

Comment: Just one question, if we had to calclate volume instead of area, are we again multiplying volume by 2, cause of two petals?

Comment: yes unless otherwise mentioned, you will have to consider both petals.